# Why doesn't my CSS stylesheet work?

Tags: html, css

I am having some trouble with a site that I have to make for school.  I've been troubling with it for a few days now.  The problem is that my CSS styling is not showing up.  Everything validates on my HTML page, and everything on the CSS page validates with the exception of my background image and a hlsa error.  The image name is "background" and I am getting this error:

18  header  Value Error : background-image Parse Error ("Module3/background.jpeg")
29  h1  Value Error : color 0 is not a color value : hlsa(0,0%,0%,0.2)

My stylesheet:

```
body 
.gradient
    {background-color:#666666;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #666666);
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    Margin:0px
    ;
}

#container { background-color: white;
    width:960px;
    padding:20px;   
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    box-shadow:5px 5px 5px #1e1e1e;
    border-radius:15px}

header {background-image: ("Module3/background.jpeg");
    background-repeat: No-repeat;
    height:150px;
    border:1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius:15px;
    }

h1 {font-family:Impact, sans-serif;
    font-size:4em;
    padding-left:15px;
    color: hlsa(0,0%,0%,0.2);}

h2 {    font-family: Impact, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: black;}
.photo {float:right;}


footer {border-style: solid;
     border-top: thick;
    font-size:.8em;
    font-style: italic; }
```

And my HTML page:

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My name</title>
<LINK href="Module3/assignment3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="w3-container">
<!--My required class information
-->

<h1>My Name</h1>

<h2>Education Goals</h2>
<img src="Module3/Sarah.jpeg" alt="Sarah" height="282" width="200">
<ul>
    <li>my goals</li>
    <li>Graduate from my school</li>
</ul>

<h2>Hobbies/Interests</h2>
<ul> 
    <li>Reading</li>
    <li>Volunteering</li>

</ul>
<h2>Favorite Web Sites</h2>
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.wikipedia.org">Wikipedia</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.mainstrike.com/mstservices/handy/insult.html">The Shakespearean Insulter</a></li>
</ul>

<footer>
<p> &copy; <a href="myschoolemail">me</a></p>
</footer>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I put it in jsfiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/ohL7a8s1/

Comment: Look up the syntax of `background-image`. It's `url()`, not just parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the `background-image` selector, you must put the value in a `url()`. Example:

```
background-image: url("Module3/background.jpeg");
```

Make sure the image is being pointed to correctly also.

Answer (score 0):

Keep you code clean and well formatted. Open developer tools and inspect broken properties. If you are not sure that you can write properties without making mistakes, use [emmet](http://emmet.io/) or similar utilities.

```css
body,
.gradient {
  background-color: #666;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #666);
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
}

#container {
  background-color: white;
  width: 960px;
  padding: 20px;   
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #1e1e1e;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

header {
  background-image: url("Module3/background.jpeg"); /* Be sure that path is exist */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
  font-size: 4em;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.2);
}

h2 {
  font-family: Impact, Sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: black;
}

.photo {
  float:right;
}

footer {
  border-style: solid;
  border-top: thick;
  font-size:.8em;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-container">
  <!--My required class information-->

  <h1>My Name</h1>

  <h2>Education Goals</h2>

  <img src="Module3/Sarah.jpeg" alt="Sarah" height="282" width="200">

  <ul>
    <li>my goals</li>
    <li>Graduate from my school</li>
  </ul>

  <h2>Hobbies/Interests</h2>

  <ul> 
    <li>Reading</li>
    <li>Volunteering</li>
  </ul>

  <h2>Favorite Web Sites</h2>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.wikipedia.org">Wikipedia</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.mainstrike.com/mstservices/handy/insult.html">The Shakespearean Insulter</a></li>
  </ul>

  <footer>
    <p> &copy; <a href="myschoolemail">me</a></p>
  </footer>
</div>
```